# WebAPI HttpContent convert to typed object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working on custom filter which should accomplish simple thing. All my APIs wrapped into 'Response' object. I want to fill in all properties using filter. This is code I have for the filter:

```
public class MeteringFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(
            HttpActionContext actionContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
        {
            var attribute =
                actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<MeterAttribute>(true).SingleOrDefault() ??
                actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<MeterAttribute>(true).SingleOrDefault();

            if (attribute == null) return continuation();

            var operation = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            var user = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
            var started = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            return continuation().ContinueWith(t => 
            {
                var completed = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                var duration = completed - started;

                var c = t.Result.Content;
                // This is code which does not work but I like to have:
                // When debugger stops here I can see Content.Value and my object but I can't use this property like below
                var cv = t.Result.Content.Value as Response<object>;

                return t.Result;
            });
        }

        public bool AllowMultiple => true;
    }
```

I found similar question where it was suggested to do `var c = t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(Response<>));` but I can't do this because I can't make lambda function `async` in this case.

Any suggestion on how to get typed object out of HttpContent so I can assign properties before it returns to caller?

Here is `Response<T>`

```
public class Response<T>
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public DateTime ServerTime { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan TimeTook { get; set; }

        public T Data { get; set; }

        public Error Error { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here is how code looks now. I do get access to object, but webservice does not respond with data I fill to client. It seems that code executed later after serialization/media formatting takes place.

I guess question becomes how do I add generic "handler" before web service returns but with access to beginning of call (so I can measure times, see request params, etc)

```
return continuation().ContinueWith(t => 
            {
                var c = t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(Response<object>), cancellationToken);
                if (c.Result is Response<object> response)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Adding times");
                    response.ServerTime = startedOn;
                    response.TimeTook = DateTime.Now - startedOn;
                }

                return t.Result;
            }, cancellationToken);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is sample web api method which I want to intercept:

```
[HttpGet]
        public Response<LookupResponseData> Carrier(int? key = null, string id = "")
        {
            return this.GetKeyIdBundleForLookup("Carriers", key, id);
        }


private Response<LookupResponseData> GetKeyIdBundleForLookup(string lookupId, int? key, string id)
        {
            if (!key.HasValue && string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                return new Response<LookupResponseData>
                {
                    Error = new Error { Code = ErrorCodes.InvalidQueryParameter, Message = "Either key or id must be specified" }
                };

            var r = new Response<LookupResponseData>();
            try
            {
                this.LookupService.GetKeyIdDescription(this.AccountId, lookupId, key, id, out var keyResult, out var idResult, out var description);
                if (!keyResult.HasValue)
                    return new Response<LookupResponseData>
                    {
                        Error = new Error { Code = ErrorCodes.InvalidOrMissingRecord, Message = "No record found for parameters specified" }
                    };

                r.Data = new LookupResponseData { Key = keyResult.Value, Id = idResult, Description = description };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.LoggerService.Log(this.AccountId, ex);
                return new Response<LookupResponseData>
                {
                    Error = new Error { Code = ErrorCodes.Unknown, Message = "API Call failed, please contact support. Details logged." }
                };
            }

            return r;
        }
```

Comment: Can't you just make the method async, await on continuation() and then extract your lambda to be be outside with async calls to ReadAsAsync? It returns a Task anyway.

Comment: I think you're doing this the really hard way.  Can you provide an example of your API Method Signature?

Comment: @ErikPhilips API calls all like this: 'public Response<SomeObject> Name(type parameters)' All I want is to do this "metadata" work outside of actions/controllers

Comment: There is a shortcut, but I need to see how one of your methods works to convert it to something simpler (sorry more than just the signature).

Comment: @ErikPhilips See EDIT2 in original post, all our methods is like that. Wrapped into "Response"

Comment: @katit are you using Core or Pre-Core?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Using regular WebApi, not Core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All my APIs wrapped into 'Response' object.

First you can simplify your results by creating a implicit operators:

```
public class Response
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime ServerTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeTook { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : Response
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Error Error { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Response<TData>(TData data)
    {
        var result = new Response<TData>
        {
          Data = data,
        };

        return result;
    }

    public static implicit operator Response<TData>(Error error)
    {
        var result = new Response<TData>
        {
          Error = error,
        };

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now it should be easier to really ignore the repeated code of creating the response:

```
private Response<LookupResponseData> GetKeyIdBundleForLookup(
  string lookupId, int? key, string id)
{
  if (!key.HasValue && string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    return new Error 
    { 
      Code = ErrorCodes.InvalidQueryParameter, 
      Message = "Either key or id must be specified" 
    };

  try
  {
    this.LookupService.GetKeyIdDescription(this.AccountId, 
      lookupId, 
      key, 
      id, 
      out var keyResult, 
      out var idResult, 
      out var description);
    if (!keyResult.HasValue)
      return new Error 
      {
        Code = ErrorCodes.InvalidOrMissingRecord, 
        Message = "No record found for parameters specified" 
      };

    return new LookupResponseData 
    { 
      Key = keyResult.Value, 
      Id = idResult, Description = description 
    };

  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    this.LoggerService.Log(this.AccountId, ex);
    return new Error 
    { 
      Code = ErrorCodes.Unknown, 
      Message = "API Call failed, please contact support. Details logged." }
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can create an [Core Async Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
public class SampleAsyncActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
  public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
    ActionExecutingContext context,
    ActionExecutionDelegate next)
  {
    // do something before the action executes
    var started = DateTimeOffset.Now;     

    // Action Executes
    var resultContext = await next();

    // do something after the action executes; resultContext.Result will be set
    if  (result.Context.Result is Response response)
    {
      response.ServerTime = started;
      response.TimeTook = DateTimeOffset.Now - started;
    }
  }
}
```

Or Non-Core (MVC):

```
public class SampleActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  private const string TimerKey = nameof(SampleActionFilter ) + "_TimerKey";

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
  {
    context.HttpContext.Items[TimerKey] = DateTimeOffset.Now;
  }

  public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
  {
    if (context.Result is Response response)
      && context.HttpContext.Items[TimerKey] is DateTimeOffset started) 
    {
      response.ServerTime = started;
      response.TimeTook = DateTimeOffset.Now - started;
    }
  }
```

Or Non-Core (WebApi):

```
public class SampleActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  private const string TimerKey = nameof(SampleActionFilter ) + "_TimerKey";

  public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
  {
    context.Request.Properties[TimerKey] = DateTimeOffset.Now;
  }

  public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
  {
    if (context.Result is Response response)
      && context.Request.Properties[TimerKey] is DateTimeOffset started) 
    {
      response.ServerTime = started;
      response.TimeTook = DateTimeOffset.Now - started;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing implicit operators! Nice one. But I can't use IAsyncActionFilter, it's not available in WebApi (not Core)

Comment: Also, this `result.Context.Result is Response response` will not work, should be Response<T> and it gives problem since I don't know and don't care what T is in this case..

Comment: Updated with Non-Core version.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I didn't notice Response object. Yep, it works great now!

Comment: I separated out `Response` from `Response<T>` because it makes it easier to cast.   And maybe you don't need `Data` sometimes.

Comment: Hm. In my case types is not the same in ActionFilterAttribute. it's `override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)` and I assume I need to use `ActionArguments` to store time?

Comment: Oh I got confused, Forgot WebApi has a different ActionFilter... onc second I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your code. I hope it helps. 
I couldn't check syntax errors though

```
return await continuation().ContinueWith(async t => 
{ 
    var result = await t;
    var c = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(Response<object>), cancellationToken);
    if (c is Response<object> response)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Adding times");
        response.ServerTime = startedOn;
        response.TimeTook = DateTime.Now - startedOn;
    }

    return result;
}, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: That doesn't work. result should be Task<HttpResponseMessage> and it returns actual HttpResponseMessage